# iphone, UITextField in UITableView

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm trying to add textfields in a tableview. I want a label and a textfield in every row except the last row. I want a switch at the last row.
The problem is that the text fields are overlapping on the rest of the rows. I moved my textfield code inside the *if(cell == nil)* but that didn't work... here's my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *MyIdentifier = @"mainMenuIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightstrip.png"]]];


    if (tableView.tag == 1) {

        UILabel *lblName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 90, 20)];
        lblName.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        lblName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        lblName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblName.tag = 31;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblName];
        [lblName release];

    }

}

    if (tableView.tag == 1) {

        [(UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:31] setText:[tableElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
// check if the last row
        if (indexPath.row == 10) {
            newsSwtich = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
            [newsSwtich addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            cell.accessoryView = newsSwtich;
        }
        else {

                UITextField *tempTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 200, 20)];
                tempTextField.delegate = self;
                //  tempTextField.placeholder = [tableElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                tempTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
                tempTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
                tempTextField.tag = indexPath.row;
                tempTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;  // no auto correction support
                tempTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;  // type of the keyboard
                tempTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  // type of the return key
                tempTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;    // has a clear 'x' button to the right
                [cell.contentView addSubview:tempTextField];
                [tempTextField release];


            cell.accessoryView = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }


cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;

}
```

When I scroll up and down the text fields are overlapped , I mean after I enter the text in the first row and scroll down, I can see that textfield copied at the last row as well.

Answer (score 1):

Cell reuse is causing the text fields to overlap. Each time the cell is being reused, you are adding a text field or a switch. These are piling up. You will need to remove the older subview which would either be the switch or the text field before adding one.

Comment: While creating a textfield/switch, assign it a tag. Say 45. Then retrieve it using `UIView *theView = [cell viewWithTag:45];`. Since now you've the view, just do `[theView removeFromSuperview];`. Alternatively, if it is a text field and you need to insert a text field, you can reset its settings to what you want. This way you can remove the need of creating it again.

Answer (score 0):

why you are using two tableviews just do this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {                          
if(indexPath.row==[tableviewarray count]){
//dont add label or textfield
}
else{
// add label or textfield
}

}
```